# How to create shortcuts for commands in .bashrc file?

Tags: linux, alias, bash

I installed Drupal 9 on a shared server, at Infomaniak. Drush and Composer are installed on it.

Currently to use Composer, I have to do the `composer2` command.

Currently to use Drush I have to do the `vendor/bin/drush` command.

I created a `.bashrc` file because it doesn't exist :

```
cd ~
touch .bashrc
nano .bashrc
```

What should I put in this file to use Drush by entering the `drush` command and how do I use composer by entering the `composer` command ?

```
source ~/.profile
alias composer="composer2"
```

I added the above code to the file, but it doesn't do anything. Here is the Infomaniak documentation for the Drush command :

https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/2152/administering-drupal-on-the-command-line-with-drush

Comment: once you add the below lines in your .bashrc file then you have to run this command to activate it : source .bashrc

Comment: @asmath `Thanks, but i have this message if i do your command linebash: /home/clients/7975f6b8hgfs6677654fghhhhggga025bi789e/.profile: No such file or directory`

Comment: Instead of source ~/.profile command you can try source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: 1) The page you link to is not clear on why you should source `~/.profile`; if it does not exist, just don't. 2) You may want to check whether the `~/.bash_profile` file exists, and whether it sources `~/.bashrc`. 3) What do you mean by "doesn't do anything"? have you tried running `alias` in a newly opened Bash instance? 4) Which version of Bash are you using? By default it should not exit when `source` fails and hence it should execute `alias composer="composer2"` regardless of the error you showed in your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in the global file. This allows me to type `la` instead of `ls -lah`:

Add the following contents to the system-wide configuration file `/etc/bash.bashrc` or the user's `~/.bashrc`, using your preferred text editor:

```bsh
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
eval "`dircolors`"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias la='ls -lah'
```

Apply changes by executing the command

```bsh
~$ source /etc/bashrc; source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the

```
source ~/.profile
```

out of .bashrc
when it's running. It's looking for ~/.profile to run, not finding it & exiting.